# How to make an integer-based value null via NHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, null, primitive-types, sqldatatypes

I have an INTEGER column that can be nulled, and mapped it to an int property. How can I change this value to null via NHibernate? int can't be nulled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use a nullable type `int?` insead of `int` and then you can map it to a nullable column in the database.

Comment: NHibernate knows about this? i.e. it will map the value correctly?

Comment: Yep it has no problems mapping to a nullable int or any nullable primitive type for that matter.

Comment: when I use type="double?", it throws a runtime error because apparently they can't resolve the type. When I use type="Nullable<Double>", it doesn't compile because I can't use "<" inside an xml attribute. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create  Map(m => m.EmployeeId).CustomType(typeof(IntConvertToNullInt));

public class IntConvertToNullInt : IUserType
    {
        public SqlType[] SqlTypes
        {
            get { return new[] { SqlTypeFactory.Int32 }; }
        }

```
    public Type ReturnedType
    {
        get { return typeof(Int32); }
    }

    public bool IsMutable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object x)
    {
        if (x == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return x.GetHashCode();
    }

    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        object obj = NHibernateUtil.Int32.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0]);
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return Convert.ToInt32(obj);
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {

        if (value == null)
        {
            NHibernateUtil.Int32.NullSafeSet(cmd, null, index);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            int indexint = (int)value;
            if (indexint == 0)
            {
                NHibernateUtil.Int32.NullSafeSet(cmd, null, index);
            }
            else
            {
                NHibernateUtil.Int32.NullSafeSet(cmd, value, index);
            }
        }            

    }

    public object DeepCopy(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
    {
        return original;
    }

    public object Assemble(object cached, object owner)
    {
        return cached;
    }

    public object Disassemble(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    bool IUserType.Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        return object.Equals(x, y);
    }
```